# How to calculated weighted proportion for a binary variable

Tags: survey, survey-sampling

I have a dataset with 100 samples of a PPS survey, and the outcome (y) is a binary variable (Y/N). I've calculated the weights for each sample, and I'm wondering how to calculate (formula) the weighted proportion and variance.

I'm using the equation: prop = sum(y_i * weight_i) / sum(weight_i), with y_i be 0 or 1. But I'm not sure if that's correct.

Thank you!

Comment: That is the weighted proportion, or more generally the weighted mean

Comment: @Henry So are they basicly the same, and just replacing mean to the proportion?

Comment: Forgetting the weighting for a moment, if you have $3$ successes and $2$ failures then the the proportion which are successes is obviously $\frac35$.  But this is equally obviously the mean of $1,1,1,0,0$.  If in your weighted question, the $y_i$ took other values then your $\frac{\sum y_i w_i}{\sum w_i}$ expression would then give the weighted mean

Comment: @Henry Got it, thank you!